# Find an entry of in a matrix of vector C++

Tags: c++, function, lambda, stl, find

I want find the element v[0][0]=1 v[0][1]=2 of the vector v with the use of lambda function and find of stl.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

   vector<vector<int>> v(3);
   v[0].resize(2);
   v[1].resize(2);
   v[2].resize(2);

   int n=1, m = 2;

   v[0][0]=1; v[0][1]=2;
   v[1][0]=0; v[1][1]=0;
   v[2][0]=2; v[2][1]=3;
  auto it = find(v.begin(), v.end(), [=]( vector<int> vet) {return (vet[0] == n && vet[1] == m);}  );

    return 0;
}
```

> error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'std::vector'
>   and 'const main()::)>')|

I don't understand the problem: both vet[0] and n are integer so the operator==  should be defined.

Comment: I think you're using the wrong algorithm... that should be find_if, unless it's from `#include "algoritmo.h"` which we don't know the contents of...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you meant to use [`find_if`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/). Moreover the syntax should be changed a bit. Also, `m` and `n` are parameters, that the lambda function should receive as parameters. So change your code to this:

```
auto it = find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [n, m] (const vector<int>& vet) {return (vet[0] == n && vet[1] == m);}  );
```

Comment: `vector<int> vet` should be `const vector<int>& vet` (imo)

Comment: #include "algoritmo.h" is non important for the question, I have delete it.